# Methodology of developing different versions of same product

Tags: php, git, project-management, versioning

I have a product in its base version, and some of my clients demands some modifications that cannot be handled by plugin structure as it's not additional feature - but heavily modified version of some of core features. The problem is that we could handle applying bug-fixes for lets say two or three clients but now it is quite hard to handle and remember to apply same code changes in various projects.

The questions is: Is there methodology explaining how to handle such a problem, and how software like GIT or other SCMs could help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is quite hard to handle and remember to apply same code changes in various projects.

`git` is perfect in your case. You can `branch` for each client and do the core modifications in the branchs. When it comes to apply bug fixes to every branch, you can either `cherry-pick` (a cool `git` feature) or `rebase` (another cool `git` feature) for each branch.